# Populate output of all values in the loop in SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, loop

I have the following code and I would like to get all the values in that loop as output. Can someone tell me the function/process we use to get that result?

```javascript
<script runat="server">
 
 Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

 var ExternalKey = "GH_7days_Counts_Log"
 var DE = DataExtension.Init(ExternalKey);

 var simpleFilter = {
  Property: "Num_Members", 
        SimpleOperator: "equals", 
        Value: "0"
 }

 var ZeroDEs = DE.Rows.Retrieve(simpleFilter);

 for(i=0; i<ZeroDEs.length; i++){
   var DeNames =ZeroDEs[i].DE_Name;
 }

 Write(DeNames);
  
</script>
```

When I use the Write I can get the output last value but I would like all the values in that loop.

Thanks

Comment: Why not put your `Write(DeNames);` inside your for-loop?  Maybe use `Write("<br>" + DeNames);` to get them each on their own line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AdamSpriggs commented, you just need to move the write into the For loop. The value of `DeNames` is overwritten through each iteration of the for loop, meaning the values are transient until the final value is assigned. To utilize each value, you need to have the actions inside of the loop.

Like this:

```js
<script runat="server">
 
 Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

 var ExternalKey = "GH_7days_Counts_Log"
 var DE = DataExtension.Init(ExternalKey);

 var simpleFilter = {
  Property: "Num_Members", 
        SimpleOperator: "equals", 
        Value: "0"
 }

 var ZeroDEs = DE.Rows.Retrieve(simpleFilter);

 for(i=0; i<ZeroDEs.length; i++){
   var DeNames =ZeroDEs[i].DE_Name;
   Write('<br>DE ' + i + ': ' + DeNames);
 }
  
</script>
```

Which should output:

```
DE 1: myDE
DE 2: myDE2
DE 3: myDE3
...
```

If you just want an array of the values and not necessarily an output, you can do something like below to retain it:

```js
<script runat="server">
 
 Platform.Load("core","1.1.1");

 var ExternalKey = "GH_7days_Counts_Log"
 var DE = DataExtension.Init(ExternalKey);
 var arr = [];

 var simpleFilter = {
  Property: "Num_Members", 
        SimpleOperator: "equals", 
        Value: "0"
 }

 var ZeroDEs = DE.Rows.Retrieve(simpleFilter);

 for(i=0; i<ZeroDEs.length; i++){
   var DeNames =ZeroDEs[i].DE_Name;
   arr.push(DeNames);
 }
  
</script>
```

Which would output an array like:

```json
["myDE","myDE2","myDE3",...]
```